# UITableViewCell with dynamic height and Auto Layout - square view in cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I'm rewriting my application to use auto layout. But I stuck on one specific problem. On main screen is table view with dynamic content. On top of every cell is square photo (with left and right align 20px). Basically something like this:

http://cl.ly/image/0N2w2g1r0w11

In real app will be more views in cell of course, but even this basic layout I can't get to work. The main problem is, that I want to specify square view width based on cell width, and this view must be always square. And cell height depends on height of this square view. It looks easy, but I tried many constraints configurations (in IB or programmatically) and always failed. This is method for cell height:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self.prototypeCell congigureCell];
    [self.prototypeCell setNeedsLayout];
    [self.prototypeCell layoutIfNeeded];
    CGSize size = [self.prototypeCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
    return size.height + 1.0;
}
```

Everything works when square view width is specified as constant. But this is not what I want (who knows what screen size will have new iPhone so I want to be prepared:)). I'm not very experienced in auto layout, so I hope that I'm only missing something obvious. I will be very grateful for every advice.

Comment: You have not provided anywhere near enough information although what you want to do seems reasonable. Firstly, you have not given any information on what is going wrong / erroring. Secondly you haven't provided any relevant source code (in this case I would expect you to show an IB screenshot or the code for the constraints). As an aside, note that from iOS 8 the height for a `UITabelViewCell` can be inferred from the constraints. My advice is add constraints to one object at a time until you run into a problem. Fix them as you go and eventually the entire cell will be correct.

Comment: That's because I try many constraints configuration and have many different errors. Or simply wrong height without any error. I was hoping that someone can suggest his own solution, not correcting any of mine.

Comment: As your question stands it should be closed because it's too broad; there are too many possible answers and not enough info o narrow the solution down. You need to bring a specific problem to StackOverflow with details on what is not working and the expected outcome for this site to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm short answer, you can always know the width of the screen on any device  with

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
```

So you could use this to calculate your square and therefore height of your cell.

Now for the much more complicated but generic answer..

You can use auto layout to size all of your cells with a small amount of sorcery.
Step 1 subclass UITableViewCell (you have probably done this anyway) and add the layoutSubviews method.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
  [super layoutSubviews];
  [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
  // any other layout stuff needed, multiline labels etc
}
```

Step 2: create a dummy cell. The reason for this is that to calculate the height of a cell you need the cell, usually you would call tableVeiw:cellForRowAtIndexPath: to do this. Problem is that this calls tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: which in turn needs the cell so calls cellForRowAtIndexPath.. you see where I'm going with this..
So in your tableViewController

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableViewCell *dummyCell;

- (UITableViewCell *)dummyCell
{
  if (!_dummyCell)
  {
      // have to dequeue if you are using a storyboard cell.
      _dummyCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellId];
  }
  return _dummyCell;
}
```

Step 3: Not strictly necessary for your simple square case, but included for completeness incase you want to do more complicated layouts. Create a configure cell method in the tableViewController.

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCellCell *)cell withModel:(id)modelObject
{
   // some custom setup using model data (labels images etc)
}
```

Step 4: Now we are at tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath *note Model is some custom DataObject you have created

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
     // get model
     Model *modelData = self.someDataArray[indexPath.row];

     //Configure
     [self configureCell:self.dummyCell withModel:modelData];

     // layout cell using width of tableview
     self.dummyCell.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds), 0); 
     [self.offscreenCell setNeedsLayout];
     [self.offscreenCell layoutIfNeeded];

     // calculate the size the cell need to draw its contents. 
     // this is where the magic happens!
     CGSize size = [self.dummyCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];

     //return the height of your cell :)
     return size.height;
}
```

And there you have it. This can be used to calculate heights for cells with any views, or dynamic sized labels assuming you use layoutSubviews and configureCell Correctly. Enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I already have this code that you are suggesting. I'm having problem with constraints configuration, that I can't get to work for correct height calculation.

Comment: In that case all you really need by the sound of it is to set the leading, trailing and top edges to your desired amount, and then use the aspect constraint to constrain it to 1:1

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the margins are, could you return the width of the tableView minus 2x the margin? It seems to me that would guarantee that the height and width of the shaded area would be equal.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    return tableView.frame.size.width - (2.0 * MARGIN);
}
```